# Azure Web App - Is it possible to put custom domain to virtual application

Tags: azure, azure-webapps, custom-domain

I have deployed 2 web application on a single azure web app using the virtual application, please refer screenshot below,

Now I want to point custom domain URL as,

**main.mydomain.com** to **app1**

and

**api.mydomain.com**  to **app2**

is it possible? if yes how to achieve that? please help.

Otherwise, I will end up creating no of WebApps for each application? Then is that the only approach?

[image]

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want visit `main.mydomain.com` and redirect to `yourwebapp.azurewebsites.net/app1` and same with app2.

If so, you could use the following rule in `web.config`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectTovirtualDirectory" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^main.mydomain.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://yourwebapp.azurewebsites.net/app1/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Hi Joey,   

Thank you for your feedback,

But in this case, my URL will show as "yourwebapp.azurewebsites.net/app1" post redirection, 
I do not want that to happen it should show *"main.mydomain.com"* only. so how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean you you want visit "yourwebapp.azurewebsites.net/app1" and redirect to "main.mydomain.com"?

Comment: See basically when we put re-direction, in that case, the browser URL also will get changed, so I do not want that to happen, so my requirement is when I want to point my custom domain to azure app URL it should show my custom domain name only, so basically the website deployed under app1 should be browsed using *main.mydomain.com*

Comment: It‘ impossible use web.config to configure custom domain to your app and not change url. you could use [application gateway with path-based routing rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal) to manage with url path.

Comment: So, I really recommend you to create two webapp for each application.

Comment: Any update now? If my reply helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Comment: if I create a web app for each application, I end up creating number of web apps, which is not cost-effective also? so there is no alternative to it?

Comment: Azure app service cost depends on the level of your app service plan. So, a signal webapp cost is equal with multiple webapps. If you use application gateway, it is more expensive than app service plan.

Comment: After all, no custom domain configuration can touch the URI paths. Also the redirect rules executed at application level will make user browsers request a different url, thus the address shown will change. So, it not satisfy your demand.

Comment: Ok thanks, Joey, I will try and post-confirmation I will accept this so that anyone referring will be guaranteed getting the correct result

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please mark it as answer.